# "Bring me the phone" instated of saying "Bring the phone to me"

Tags: syntax

What's more natural for the native English speakers ear?

> "**Bring me** the phone please"
>
> "**Bring** the phone to **me** please"

My doubt with the first sentence (bring me...) which can sounds a little bit not logic, and sounds like I ask to bring me... (take me from one place to another). If it's valid, then how can you **explain me** the logic behinds this sentence?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78705/discussion-on-question-by-intrigued-by-proliferation-bring-me-the-phone-instat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few verbs in English take two objects. in the old days at least, these were called the direct and indirect object. (In Old English, they were distinguished by case endings for accusative and dative cases respectively.)

In modern English, which has eliminated most case endings, grammatical function depends on position. If a verb can take both a direct and indirect object, it must have a direct object but may lack an indirect object. If the verb has both kinds of object, there are two ways to specify which is which: the indirect object can precede the direct object or the indirect object can follow the direct object plus **to.**

**Bring the phone here** is grammatical; **phone** is the direct object, and there is no indirect object.

**Bring me the phone** is grammatical; **phone** is the direct object, and **me** is the indirect object.

**Bring the phone to me** is grammatical; **phone** is the direct object, and **me** is the indirect object.

In older modern English, indirect objects were used in a broader sense than is common today. We today would not say **Open me that door** to mean **Open that door for me**, but 16th century speakers would have.

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> Bring to me the phone please.

and not be wrong, but it will sound a little stilted as unless you are trying to be wordy for clarity, the *to* in that pattern is almost always omitted.

If you wanted to be brought (or given, etc.) to the phone, you'd say

> Bring me to the phone please.

*Bring* is among a few verbs in English that take 2 objects.  To *give* means to provide X to Y, and all 2 object verbs have meanings that are some form of "providing" X to Y.

> show Y X - provide a view of X to Y
>
> lend Y X - provide X to Y with expectation that Y will return X.
>
> read Y X - provide a vocal rendition of text of X to Y
>
> post Y X - give X to Y via mail, sign, bulletin board.
>
> make Y X - provide X to Y by creating it

Etc.

When you explain X, in a sense, you "provide" information about X.  Hence the temptation to make it follow the same pattern as *bring*, *give*, or other 2 object verbs.

As far as the logic of English word order, that's hard to say, but language doesn't have to have logic to work, it only needs to be something everyone agrees on and be composed of something people can discern and manipulate.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you. So, "Bring me the phone please" (in meaning of bring to me the phone) is correct? and explain me is not correct. Yes?